# Copiar al portapapeles con import os Python. No sale bien

Tags: python

tardes o noches.

Quiero copiar al portpapales la salida de un texto en Python. Dejo el codigo.

El caso es que me da el siguiente error.

```
TypeError: system() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias

```py
import os

cadena = input("Introduce los usuarios: ")

lista = cadena.split()


print(lista)

f = open ('salida2.txt','w')
for i in lista:
    codigo = print(f"Aqui el codigo {i}@correo Aqui la otra parte del codigo {i}@correo2 ")

    os.system(codigo)


input(print("Exit"))
```

Comment: Si sabes que `print` regresa `None`? Si deseas copiar al portapapeles algo puedes usar el módulo `clipboard`

Answer (score 0):

`print()` retorna `None`. Por tanto, con

```
codigo = print(f"Aqui el codigo {i}@correo Aqui la otra parte del codigo {i}@correo2 ")
```

`codigo` vale `None`, lo que produce el error en la siguiente instrucción:

```
os.system(codigo)
```

**Solución**

Eliminar el `print`. Los f-strings funcionan en cualquier parte, no sólo dentro del `print`:

```
codigo = f"Aqui el codigo {i}@correo Aqui la otra parte del codigo {i}@correo2 "
os.system(codigo)
```